# Stop pending actions for jquery debounce on keyup (And double keypress)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that is using a plugin called debounce.

Plugin information: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

I've run into a problem where the keypress events still run after keyup event because of the delay from debounce.

For instance... if you were to double click spacebar, the function still runs even though you didn't hold it down for over a second.

It's hard to explain my issue. I basically need a `stop()` function to run after keyup event to stop any more text being appended.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cTZJU/133/

Code:

```
function appendFunc() {
    $('.output').append('Keypress running');
}


//Debounce the function running too often
$(document).keypress($.throttle(appendFunc, 1500));



$(document).keyup(function() {
    /**
    * I want to stop any pending keypress actions.
    * - Including double keypress
    */
});
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what functionality you're attempting to implement? You mention both 'throttle' and 'debounce' in your question; these are different actions. If I throttle an event with a time of 1s, then the event will run every 1s so long as the triggering action is occurring. If I debounce that same event, it will only execute once, 1s after the final instance of the triggering action occurs. Additionally, you mention a keydown event that isn't included in your code snippet.

Comment: the plugin should have some parameter controlling the delay for debounced function or throttle function (it is not documented but it should be there), you can manipulate that. Also you can add event handlers in jquery namespaced and remove them based on namespace, so if all else fails try to remove and re-add the (namespaced) event handlers for specific removal

Comment: jack - Sorry for the confusion. I mean debounce not throttle. Nikos - I'm looking for some docs to set settings but I can't find anything online. Is there any reference? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $(document).clearQueue(); in the function called on keyup.

```
$(document).keyup(function() {

       $(document).clearQueue();

});
```

You will have to bind each event on the document as a queue then only you can use clearQueue. 
You can do it  like as follows:

```
$(document).queue(function(){  

        $(this).keypress(function(){ });   

});
```

Comment: i think [`.clearQueue`](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) method is for clearing queued animations, not events in general

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You will have to bind each event on the document as a queue then only you can use clearQueue. You can do it  like as follows:$(document).queue(function(){  $(this).keypress(function(){ })    });

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked like a charm using it that way!